# Populating an array iterating over an object in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to upload multiple files using third party ngx-file-drop component in my Angular 7 application.

I am iterating through files object which is of the type `NgxFileDropEntry`. This object has only two properties called `fileEntry` and `relativePath`. While looping through the object however, I am able to assign `selectedDocumentItem` and `selectedDate` in HTML code.

These properties are visible during runtime in the component while debugging, but complains at compile time. I had used the above approach so that I could save records when the user clicks the upload button as all values are available via the object.

Before I can save the object, I need to populate the `uploadDocument` object with the values from the files object to pass it to the service.

I am not able to populate the `uploadDocument` object. Any issues with my logic. Is there an alternative to for loop that I am using?

```
<div class="upload-table">
    <table id="table1" class="center">

        <tbody class="upload-name-style">
            <tr *ngFor="let item of files; let i=index">
                <td> <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="item.relativePath" style="width: 350px" /></td>
                <td>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDocumentItem" 
                        [data]="DocumentTypes" [defaultItem]="defaultItem" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                        valueField="Id">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <kendo-datepicker style="width: 200px" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'"
                        [(ngModel)]="item.selectedDate"></kendo-datepicker>
                </td>
                <td> <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="deleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete
                    </button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
```

JSON

```
[{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":6,"Name":"Constitutional Documents"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-09T23:00:00.000Z"},{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":10,"Name":"Manager Letters"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-13T23:00:00.000Z"},{"relativePath":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","fileEntry":{"name":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"selectedDocumentItem":{"Id":7,"Name":"Regulation / References"},"selectedDate":"2019-07-30T23:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Component

```
document: IDocument ;
uploadDocument: IDocument[] = [];
public files: NgxFileDropEntry[] = [];

  public createDocument() {
    console.log(this.files);

  this.files.forEach(element => {

        this.uploadDocument.forEach(doc => {

            doc.id = 5508,
            doc.documentTypeId = element.selectedDocumentItem.Id ,
            doc.name = element.relativePath,
            doc.documentDate = element.selectedDate

          });


    });
```

Attempted solution based on Darren's suggestion

html

```
 <div class="upload-table">
        <table id="table1" class="center">



            <tbody class="upload-name-style">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of documents; let i=index">
                    <td> <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="item.fileDropEntry.relativePath" style="width: 350px" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="item.documentTypeId" 
                            [data]="DocumentTypes" [defaultItem]="defaultItem" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                            valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <kendo-datepicker style="width: 200px" [format]="'dd MMM, yyyy'"
                            [(ngModel)]="item.documentDate"></kendo-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td> <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="deleteRow(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete
                        </button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
```

Component

```
    export interface IDocumentUpload {
        fileDropEntry: NgxFileDropEntry;
        id: number;
        name: string;
        documentTypeId: number;
        documentDate: Date;
    }

 documents : IDocumentUpload[] = [];

     public createDocument() {
            console.log(this.documents);
     }


 public dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
    this.files = files;
    for (const droppedFile of files) {

        // Is it a file?
        if (droppedFile.fileEntry.isFile) {
            const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;
            fileEntry.file((file: File) => {

                // Here you can access the real file
                console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, file);
                console.log('Hello');

                /**
                // You could upload it like this:
                const formData = new FormData()
                formData.append('logo', file, relativePath)

                // Headers
                const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                  'security-token': 'mytoken'
                })

                this.http.post('https://mybackend.com/api/upload/sanitize-and-save-logo', formData, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' })
                .subscribe(data => {
                  // Sanitized logo returned from backend
                })
                **/

            });
        } else {
            // It was a directory (empty directories are added, otherwise only files)
            const fileEntry = droppedFile.fileEntry as FileSystemDirectoryEntry;
            console.log(droppedFile.relativePath, fileEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is a [superset](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1) of JavaScript.

It exists simply to be a *compile-time* layer that enforces types (something that is lacking in vanilla JS). This is why you only get a *compile-time* error and not a runtime one.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop/blob/master/src/ngx-file-drop/ngx-file-drop-entry.ts) for `NgxFileDropEntry` I can see that it does indeed only have two properties, namely `relativePath` and `fileEntry` so of course the compiler will complain when you try to access properties that do not exist on that **type** (the ones you added).

What I would suggest doing is create your own custom type to wrap the `NgxFileDropEntry` which also contains your custom properties. Something like this:

```
export interface SomeCustomNameThatMakeseSense {
  fileDropEntry: NgxFileDropEntry;
  documentItem: WhateverTheTypeOfThisIs;
  date: Date;
}
```

Then wherever you are getting your `files` from, you simple instantiate a new one of `SomeCustomNameThatMakeseSense` and use that in your HTML to add properties to.

EDIT:

It seems there has been some confusion so I want to clear things up by adding more of an explanation:

What I was suggesting for you to do, was to create **new** objects of type `SomeCustomNameThatMakeseSense` (from above) which *wrap* your `files` array. You don't want to be casting **existing** objects to this new type because that just hides the issue.

Change:

```
public files: NgxFileDropEntry[] = [];
```

To:

```
public files: SomeCustomNameThatMakeseSense[] = [];
```

Change:

```
public dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
  this.files = files;
 // Other code removed for the sake brevity 
}
```

To:

```
public dropped(files: NgxFileDropEntry[]) {
  this.files = files.map(file => ({
    fileDropEntry: file,
    documentItem: undefined, // Give this a default value of your own choice
    date: new Date() // Same here as above
  }));
  // Other code removed for the sake brevity 
}
```

Then in your HTML change:

```
*ngFor="let item of documents; let i=index"
```

To:

```
*ngFor="let item of files; let i=index"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question but we aren't *changing* any types. We are *creating* new ones that *wrap* the previous ones which allows us to append some additional data (such as the date and document).

Comment: Oh ok. I am getting bit confused with the field names that you have used in the dropped event. Doent match the interface fields that i have defined

Comment: Oh, I used the one that I created in my post. Yes you have additional fields now in your edited answer so you will need to use those too. The point I am trying to make stays the same. You need to try to understand what it is we're doing here. Once you do, it won't matter what fields are used :) All that we are doing is taking an object of **some type** and **wrapping** it into a **new type** that we created ourselves. That's all. This **new type** simple has our own custom fields that we can use to logically add extra data to the original.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196006/discussion-between-tom-and-darren-ruane).